# Would strenuous exercise make one more susceptible to ringworm?

Tags: exercise, immune-system, ringworm

A [recent study](http://www.nytimes.com/2018/04/25/well/move/how-strenuous-exercise-affects-our-immune-system.html) debunks the generally-held belief that strenuous exercise suppresses the immunity system. Instead, immunity cells are said to migrate to internal organs that need them most after exercise, e.g., lungs, gut.  To me, this still seems to suppress immunity in the remaining organs, e.g., the skin.  Wouldn't this make people more susceptible to skin infections like ringworm, especially in sweaty post-exercise conditions?